# Embedded Image Issue Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So what I'm wanting is to put in my apps logo as an embedded png. Watched a good few tutorials & I feel I have genuinely replicated all paths but it still doesn't show (Obviously I'm doing something wrong lol). What I currently have is no image at all even when I am typing in "local:ImageResource APRooved.Logoforappheader.png" I get to "APRooved" where it still suggests its a source & as soon as I put that full stop in it then says "No Suggestions". My images are currently in Android & iOS resource folders as its a cross platform application & the properties are set to EmbeddedResource.

Does anyone have any idea or can put me in the right direction?

Below is my XAML Snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:APRooved"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="APRooved.MainPage"
         xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;    assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
        BarBackgroundColor="#2B333F"
        BarTextColor="#FFA600">

<ContentPage Title="Calculator" IconImageSource="Logoforappheader.png">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width ="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width ="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <BoxView Color="#2B333F"
            CornerRadius="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="3"   
            WidthRequest="700"
            HeightRequest="200"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />


    <Image Source="{local:ImageResource APRooved.Logoforappheader.png}" WidthRequest="300"     HeightRequest="100"
           Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="1"></Image>
```

below is my Image Resource Extension

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace APRooved
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Source))]
    public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Source == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source,     typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

            return imageSource;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you should not need any special code to load an image that is an embedded resource in the platform project.  You only need to do that if the images are resources of the shared project.  Please read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My images are currently in Android & iOS resource folders as its a
>   cross platform application

If the images are [local images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images), you should put them in the right place under each project.

**iOS** - The preferred way to manage and support images since iOS 9 is to use Asset Catalog Image Sets, which should contain all of the versions of an image that are necessary to support various devices and scale factors for an application.

**Android** - Place images in the Resources/drawable directory with Build Action: `AndroidResource`. `High- and low-DPI` versions of an image can also be supplied.

**Universal Windows Platform (UWP)** - Place images in the application's root directory with Build Action: Content.

Then load image by :

```
<Image Source="xxx.jpg" />
```

If the images are [Embedded images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images), they should be placed in the shared project and load them like the ways you did in your question.